# HTML TODOs in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-7.1

I wanted to add some TODO: tags in my .html file, but it does not seem to work properly.

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.

This seemed to work (added PHP comments):

```
<!-- // TODO: foo -->
<!-- /* TODO: foo */ -->
```

However, in both cases Netbeans says:

> TODO: foo -->

Is there some way to avoid the "-->" ?

Thanks,
Niklas

edit: [I've opened a thread in the netbeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=134343#134343)

Comment: `<?php //TODO: foo ?>` ;> but it will work...

Comment: ok so it won't work it will still add the closing `?>`, however mine seems to work just fine in an html file using normal html comments `<!-- TODO:foo -->` however if I add the C style comments (//) it always displays the trailing characters. I'm using ver 7.2 rc1

Comment: I'm not currently using Netbeans, but would it not be possible to split the comment over separate lines? Like `<?php` or `<!--` on one line, then `Todo:Foo` on the next, and the ending `?>` or `-->` on the third?

Comment: `<!-- /* TODO:foo */ -->` spread over 3 lines works. Thank you!